# ESC key crashes/closes LibreOffice Impress when in presentation mode

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice

When in Impress's presentation mode, pressing the ESC key exits the app entirely, rather than closing the presentation mode and returning to the main Impress app.

How can I return the behavior to how it was before 5.3.0.3?

Is this a bug, or intended behavior? I can't tell if the app is exiting or crashing. When I restart the app, it asks to help recover files that had been open, which leads me to think that this is an unintended crash.

I've checked all the option dialog boxes, but haven't found anything to fix. The ESC key is not mapped to anything in the key-remapping dialog box.  Should I set the ESC key to a specific value to avoid this crashing?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10, kernel 4.9.8, LibreOffice 5.3.0.3.

Note: Impress seems to crash also when I try to close the presentation by right-clicking the presentation and selecting "End Show".

Thanks very much

Comment: Why not try the current versions instead? 5.3 or 5.25 available [direct](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) or a more current version from the [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libreoffice&searchon=names)

Comment: @ElderGeek: Sorry about my mistyping. I meant that I am using LO version 5.3.0.3 -- the most recent version. I've updated my question. Thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: HAve you considered uninstalling 5.3.03 and reverting back to the version available in the repositories?

Comment: @ElderGeek: I'll roll back to 5.2.5 if there isn't a work-around.

Comment: It's likely a [bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=impress) Cutting edge development often causes minor  bleeding

Comment: @ElderGeek: I've used my share of band-aids over the years...  :-)